# Resync edited Flutter source files

Tags: git, flutter

Imagine that I have some source file (e.g. `widget.dart` from the Flutter framework) that I edited internally.
Now, I *still want to have the file get overriden by changes on GitHub*.
I know that there was a change to the **`master`** branch on GitHub regarding my edited file, but, upon executing `flutter upgrade`, my edited file remains untouched.

Also, how come that `flutter upgrade` does ***not*** eliminate all internal changes, i.e. override all files with the latest from Git?

Comment: flutter upgrade is not meant to be used by developers contributing to the Flutter framework, instead a fully git based workflow is expected - see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Comment: @JonahWilliams I am not talking about contributing. I just noticed that a source code file was internally outdated for me and added the information that I know that it has been changed and that I potentially changed it internally (not to push it to Git).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can occur if a change has not been pushed to a specific branch in Git.
`flutter channel master` will use the latest changes and also move to the `master` branch.